# how to import images from excel sheet to database in php

Tags: php, excel, database

this is the code i Have used to insert the data from excel sheet to db.
but here i want to insert images from excel sheet to db.
but if i try the file which contain images it goes to the else part of the code.

is there any differnt functions there for upload the image into to db

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <br>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
 <button type="submit" id="submit" name="import" class="btn-submit">Import</button>
</form>
<?php

//excel sheet data insert
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hep");
require_once('C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\php-excel-reader\excel_reader2.php');
require_once('C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"])){
  $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];
  //echo $_FILES["file"]["type"];
  //exit;
  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)==false){
   echo "only Excel Files Supported";
  } else {
    $targetPath = 'import/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
    $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);
    $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
  // print_r($sheetCount);
  //exit;
  for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++){
      $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
      foreach ($Reader as $Row) {
        $name = "";
        if(isset($Row[0])) {
            $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[0]);
        }
        $email = "";
        if(isset($Row[1])) {
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[1]);
        }

        if (!empty($name) || !empty($description)) {
          $query = "insert into form(no,name) values('".$name."','".$email."')";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
          if (! empty($result)) {
             echo "Excel Data Imported into the Database";
          } else {
              echo "Problem in Importing Excel Data";
          }
        }
   }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

if you have any idea please post your answers..
thanks in advance.